# Why XMLHttpRequest doesn't work with "www."?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, redirect

I have following code:

```
var params = {
            cache:false, 
            dataType:"json", 
            type:"GET",
            url: "/order.php",
            error: function(data){
                dump(data);
            },
            success: function (data){
              alert('ok');
            },
            data:{
                js:1
            }
        };

$.ajax(params);
```

So if I run example.com it gets work perfect.
But if I run www.example.com I get an error via my function dump().
Google console shows an error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   =1345470451769">http://example.com/order.php?js=1&tariff=247&=1345470451769. Origin
>   http://www.example.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

What does it mean?

So I don't need any permanent redirect from www.domain.com to domain.com.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**update 1:**
I added function:

```
function getBaseUrl()
{
   var baseUrl = '';
   baseUrl += location.protocol + '//';
   baseUrl += location.hostname;

   return baseUrl;
}
```

and change url: "/order.php" on  url: getBaseUrl() + "/order.php"

got the same error.
Am I doing something wrong here?

**Update 2:**
I added this one to htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://sample.com http://www.sample.com
</IfModule>
```

It seems my hosting doesn't support it, because I still get an error for www.

Comment: Browsers don't allow a page to make an XHR to a URL in a different domain (unless the target site explicitly allows it via special headers). It's called the ["Same Origin Policy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Comment: Subdomains count as different domains, i.e. you run into the same-origin policy.

Comment: does it mean I should call url:'htp://www.sample.com/order.php' instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you've got there means that you can't make a `XMLHttpRequest` from one domain to another unless the target domain specifies in its response header that you're allowed to do this. It's a security measure enforced by the browser.

The entire domain has to match, so example.com can't make a `XMLHttpRequest` request to www.example.com and vice-versa.

You could just use some javascript to get the URL based on the current document location, or use relative paths instead.

Also make sure the webserver isn't doing a silent redirect from one domain to another as this may also cause permissions issues.

The alternative if you have access to the webserver is to add the appropriate cross domain headers to the response - http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/

Example:
`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.example.com http://example.com`

Edit: The domains in the above list need to be space separated, not comma.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://sample.com http://www.sample.com"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I use relative paths in this example, isn't it?

Comment: If you're using relative paths and it doesn't work, I'd be pointing fingers at the webserver. Make sure it's not doing an automatic redirect from one domain to another. Updated answer with additional solutions.

Comment: there are not automatic redirect because I can run sample.com both www.sample.com

Comment: ok, thanks. I will prepend the base href location to my GET link I think.

Comment: Try adding the response headers that I suggested. You can do it either via the webserver globally or just on the script processing the request.

Comment: Updated. The domains in the list are separated with spaces, not commas or anything else.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15573/discussion-between-phonicuk-and-anthony)

Answer (score 2):

Subdomains are considered a different domain with the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). Use a relative path if you site functions with or without www.

If the server redirects, why is the current page not on www?

From a SEO standpoint, you probably want the server to do the redirects to one version of the url or the other.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot do redirect from www\. to \. it depends on SEO as you say.

Comment: than cors is your answer, but it will fail on older browsers.